# Getting a django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError using ajax

Tags: django, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest, crud

I am trying to use the ajax post function to post data from my contact form in one of my templates. However, I am getting a 'django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError' when I make the request.

The error is a server error and it is displayed as shown

```
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'name'
```

It is being triggered in the view.py folder on the line with the code

```
name = request.POST['name']
```

Here is my model for the message:

```
class Message(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     content = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
     created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This is my view.py:

```
def save_message(request):
     if request.method=='POST':
          name = request.POST['name']
          email = request.POST['email']
          content = request.POST['content']
          Message.objects.create(
               content = content,
               name = name,
               email = email
          )
          messages.success(request, f'Your message has been sent. Expect a response soon!')
          return JsonResponse({'bool':True})
```

This is the form in the index template

```
{% csrf_token %}
                     <form class="contactForm" id="contactForm">
                         <div class="form-floating">
                             <input class="form-control" class="message-name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name..." />
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-floating">
                             <input class="form-control" class="message-email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email..." />
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-floating">
                             <textarea class="form-control" id="message" class="message-text" placeholder="Enter your message here..."></textarea>
                         </div>
                         <br />
                         
                         <button class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase save-message" id="submitButton" type="submit">Send</button>
                     </form>
```

And this is my ajax:

```
{% block script %}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    

        // This is for the post messages for non-logged in users
        $(".save-message").on('click',function(){
            var _content=$(".message-text").val();
            var _messageName=$(".message-name").val();
            var _messageEmail=$(".message-email").val();
            // Ajax 
            $.ajax({
                url:"/save-message",
                type:"POST",
                data:{
                    content:_content,
                    name:_messageName,
                    email:_messageEmail,
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken:"{{csrf_token}}"
                },
                dataType:'json',
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $(".save-message").addClass('disabled').text('Saving...');
                },
                success:function(res){
                    if(res.bool==true){
                        $(".message-text").val('');
                    }
                    $(".save-message").removeClass('disabled').text('submit');
                }
            });     
        });

  });


</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `request.POST[]` is for data sent with regular HTML forms, but not when sending data using AJAX (even if it is sent via POST).  To access that you need the raw, `request.body`, and to parse that you need `json`, which also means you need to `import json`:

```py
import json

def save_message(request):
    
    if request.method=='POST':
        
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        
        name = data['name']
        email = data['email']
        content = data['content']
        
        Message.objects.create(
           content = content,
           name = name,
           email = email
        )

        messages.success(request, f'Your message has been sent. Expect a response soon!')

        return JsonResponse({'bool':True})
```

The error would have occurred with `email = request.POST['email']` or `content = request.POST['content']` because `request.POST` is empty, so the keys, `name`, `email`, `content`, or any other key would have raised the `MultiValueDictKeyError:`.

Source: [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body):

> **HttpRequest.body**
>
> The raw HTTP request body as a bytestring. This is
> useful for processing data in different ways than conventional HTML
> forms: binary images, XML payload etc. For processing conventional
> form data, use **HttpRequest.POST**.